# Stack overflow happening when changing a line which is never reached - why and how to prevent it?

Tags: c, pointers, embedded, stack-overflow

I'm developing something in an embedded context with Zephyr.

Essentially I'm dealing with a boot-loop caused by a stack overflow. The stack overflow goes away when I change an **unused** parameter of a function call deep inside my main. To make sure that the problem is not with the inside of the function, I hard-coded its implementation to be `return 0;`.

The offending line being like such creates a boot loop:

```
uint8_t port;
ret = foo(&port, NULL, NULL);
```

But the line missing the de-referenced port has the code run normally:

```
uint8_t port;
ret = foo(NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Mind you, as I've already said, the implementation of foo is hard-coded to return 0. The parameters are at no point used. Furthermore, I'm sure the line is never actually reached at runtime (in this case) as it lives behind some conditionals requiring my interaction to actually go through.

I've started to give up and blame things on faulty memory or ESD damage but when I tried the same code with the same changes on a spare piece of hardware I had laying around the same thing happens. What is it that I'm missing? I genuinely don't know what else I could do to find out why this is happening and how to fix it. I don't have an access to a debugger for this microcontroller (SAMD21) so I'm at a bit of a loss... Any ideas (or at least sympathy)?

Comment: did you try to look at the assembly code? the compiler may have produced really different code for some reason.

Comment: Look at assembler, place a sentinel on the stack and see how close you are to overflow, and carefully look at your map file to be sure everything is fitting the way you think in memory.  If things are really, really close to overflow, then reduce sizes or reorg memory a bit.

Comment: You can check sentinel values at runtime with careful printf() usage :)

Comment: @MichaelDorgan it would not work in that case because a a boot loop would prevent printf() to even execute!

Comment: Undefined behavior in general, and stack overflows in particular, tend to behave so that when you change an unrelated line of code, you expose or hide the problem. That doesn't mean that the particular line is the offender though, the problem could be anywhere. On a modern M0+ like SAMD + a decent debugger, it should be possible to set a write breakpoint at the bottom of the stack and then you'll see exactly where the code went wrong, including instruction trace. Meaning you'd solve the bug in 20 minutes instead of 1 week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I've found the culprit - a simple stack overflow. I was one byte away from it before the addition of the `uint8_t port` variable declaration into main. The variable when not used as a parameter in `foo()` was being optimised away by the compiler. Having one fewer byte on the call stack apparently was enough to prevent the overflow.

Solution: increase stack size and be more careful with clogging it up with unnecessary items.

Answer (score 0):

When you remove that parameter does it run without any errors or are there other errors? If you are writing to the wrong memory (e.g. memory that was allocated with a size of zero) somewhere in your program, changes to unrelated parts of the program's code, such as changing the size of a struct, or the parameters of a function, could change where a fatal error occurs and what kind of fatal error it is.